# SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler support for dead DLQ

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

Currently we use SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and publishing failed records to dead letter topic using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer. We are now changing our code to consume batch of records, which requires BatchErrorHandler to be implemented, but SeekToBatchErrorHandler doesn't support DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer to publish records to Dead letter topic. Can anyone guide how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be support for this because the framework doesn't know which record in the batch failed; all it could do is send the whole batch to the DLT which is not really what (most) people would want.

Errors within a batch must be handled within the listener itself.