# Spring Cloud Stream deserialization error handling for Batch processing

Tags: batch-processing, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a question about handling deserialization exceptions in Spring Cloud Stream while processing batches (i.e. `batch-mode: true`).

Per the documentation here, https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.5.12.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer, (looking at the implementation of `FailedFooProvider`), it looks like this function should return a subclass of the original message.

Is the intent here that a list of both Foo's and BadFoo's will end up at the original `@StreamListener` method, and then it will be up to the code (i.e. me) to sort them out and handle separately? I suspect this is the case, as I've read that the [automated DLQ sending isn't desirable for batch error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60092423/seektocurrentbatcherrorhandler-support-for-dead-dlq), as it would resubmit the whole batch.

And if this is the case, what if there is more than one message type received by the app via different `@StreamListener`'s, say Foo's and Bar's. What type should the value function return in that case? Below is the pseudo code to illustrate the second question?

```java
@StreamListener
public void readFoos(List<Foo> foos) {
    List<> badFoos = foos.stream()
        .filter(f -> f instanceof BadFoo)
        .map(f -> (BadFoo) f)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
   // logic
}
@StreamListener
public void readBars(List<Bar> bars) {
  // logic
}


// Updated to return Object and let apply() determine subclass
public class FailedFooProvider implements Function<FailedDeserializationInfo, Object> {

  @Override
  public Object apply(FailedDeserializationInfo info) {
    if (info.getTopics().equals("foo-topic") {
        return new BadFoo(info);
    }
    else if (info.getTopics().equals("bar-topic") {
        return new BadBar(info);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Be aware that `@StreamListener` has long been deprecated in favor of functional approach - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages. 
Yes, to your first question while I am not sure what you're asking with the second one

Comment: I updated with pseudo code. Hope that provides clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the list will contain the function result for failed deserializations; the application needs to handle them.

The function needs to return the same type that would have been returned by a successful deserialization.

You can't use conditions with batch listeners. If the list has a mixture of Foos and Bars, they all go to the same listener.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have updated my question w/ a small code sample to illustrate my second question, as I don't think I was very clear. I'm not trying to use conditions, I just have multiple @StreamListeners which take different message formats. With only one value function, how can I update it to handle all scenarios? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You should be able to return `Object` and use the topic (or other information) in the `FailedDeserializationInfo` to determine what type to create.

Comment: Are offset and partition included in the FailedDeserializationInfo object? I'm not seeing them in it.

Comment: The `Deserializer` is not provided with that information by the kafka-clients (see its javadocs). They are available in the record with the value set to whatever the function returns.

Comment: I'm not sure which record you're referencing. I've updated as your answer explains, but inside readFoos I'm still not able to see any metadata (for Foos or BadFoos)

Comment: The intent is to take the BadFoos and send them to a dlq, along with with partition/offset.

Comment: You can either change the listener to `...(List<ConsumerRecord<?, Foo>> foos)`, or you can add more parameters `@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offset)s`. The positions in the lists correspond to the positions in the `foos` list.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#consumer-record-metadata